# Rails 4: Public Activity Gem and Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-api

I am using the Public Activity Gem to track post for my app. Out of the box Public Activity gives me a ActivitiesController. I want to convert this controller to an API Controller so that I can make request to it from a mobile app. Below is the code I'm currently using. How can I rewrite the controller.

```
    class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
       before_action :authenticate_user!

       def index
        @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
       end

   end

class Api::V1::ActivitiesController < Api::BaseController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
    return render json: {message: "Activity Success"}
  end

end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
   namespace :api do
         scope module: :v1 do
             # devise_scope :api_v1_user do
                 resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
                 # devise_for :users, :controllers => {passwords: 'api/v1/passwords'}
                 resources :activities, :only => [:index]
             # end
         end
     end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#creating-a-new-application

Focus on the "render json:" parts...